# Payment has not arrived at destination!

Tags: blockchain

I do not know yet whether is this transaction is confirmed or not because not yet reached the destination !!
https://blockchain.info/tx/962a428acb10ed071b1cf954cbaf763016751b986429df5268424880ee95a7d6.
Can someone help me with advice on what to do

Answer (score 3):

The transaction was confirmed according to the transaction ID you provided (727 Confirmations as of this moment). Have whoever you sent to Bitcoin to check again.

Comment: How can i check again if my wallet is empty? tanks

Comment: You need to make sure your wallet sees all the recent blocks. Check it's got connectivity to peers to get the blockchain from. Or if you are using a SPV wallet, maybe find another node. If you are using a third party wallet (ie, one you don't have the private keys to), you're at their mercy.

Comment: And how i do this?thanx